# Large Input Causes Topological Sort To BreakDown

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, runtime-error, graph-theory

Question:-

Now you can take online courses in the Berland State University! Polycarp needs to pass k main online courses of his specialty to get a diploma. In total n courses are availiable for the passage.

The situation is complicated by the dependence of online courses, for each course there is a list of those that must be passed before starting this online course (the list can be empty, it means that there is no limitation).

Help Polycarp to pass the least number of courses in total to get the specialty (it means to pass all main and necessary courses). Write a program which prints the order of courses.

Polycarp passes courses consistently, he starts the next course when he finishes the previous one. Each course can't be passed more than once.

Input:-

The first line contains n and k (1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 105) — the number of online-courses and the number of main courses of Polycarp's specialty.

The second line contains k distinct integers from 1 to n — numbers of main online-courses of Polycarp's specialty.

Then n lines follow, each of them describes the next course: the i-th of them corresponds to the course i. Each line starts from the integer ti (0 ≤ ti ≤ n - 1) — the number of courses on which the i-th depends. Then there follows the sequence of ti distinct integers from 1 to n — numbers of courses in random order, on which the i-th depends. It is guaranteed that no course can depend on itself.

It is guaranteed that the sum of all values ti doesn't exceed 10^5.

Output:-

If Not Possible ,-1

If Possible, then print the number of courses he needs to take followed by the order in which he takes the courses

Code with comments:-

```
import sys
flag=True
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000000)
c=[];st=[];
def topo(s):#Traversing the array and storing the vertices
    global c,st,flag;
    c[s]=1; #Being Visited
    for i in adjli[s]:#visiting neighbors
        if c[i]==0:
            topo(i)
        if c[i]==1:
            flag=False# If Back Edge , Then Not Possible
    st.append(str(s))
    c[s]=2 # Visited

try:
    n,k=map(int,input().split(' '))#Number Of Courses,Dependencies
    main=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))#Main Dependencies
    depen=[]#Dependencies List
    for i in range(n):
        depen.append(list(map(int,input().split(' ')))[1:]);c.append(0)#Append Input To Dependencies List, Marking Visited as 0(False)
    c.append(0)
    adjli=[]
    adjli.append(main)#Assuming Main Course at index 0 with dependencies as Main Dependency(main)
    for i in range(len(depen)):
        adjli.append(depen[i])#Appending Other Dependencies
    topo(0)#TopoLogical Sort Order
    st.pop(-1)#popping the assumed Main Couse
    if flag:# IF possible then print
        print(len(st))
        print(' '.join(st))
    else:
        print(-1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e,"error")
```

What did I do?

I did a topological sort and stored the traversal order. I assumed the Specialty Course to be stored at Index 0 and formed the graph accordingly. If a BackEdge Was encountered I returned -1.

What's the Problem?

The code gave correct output for small inputs but encountered a Runtime Error in case of large Inputs like:-

Code to generate Input:-

```
print(100000,1)
print(100000)
for i in range(100000):
  if i==0:
    print(i)
  else:
    print(1,i)
```

What did I do to tackle the problem?

I tried to print the runtime error but nothing was displayed.

Link to the Question:-[Question](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/770/C)

My Solution:-[Solution](https://codeforces.com/problemset/submission/770/42144572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem with the stack during recursion. Python has a low recursion limit issue even if you stated this limit explicitly. This problem is mentioned in this codeforces blog: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/45135/

One solution is to implement function topo using an iterative approach rather than the recursive approach.

The changed code can be:

```
import sys
flag=True
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000000000)
c=[];st=[];
cur_adj=[]
def topo(s):#Traversing the array and storing the vertices
    global c,st,flag;
    stack = [s]
    while(stack):
        s = stack[-1]
        c[s]=1; #Being Visited
        if(cur_adj[s] < len(adjli[s])):
            cur = adjli[s][cur_adj[s]]
            if(c[cur]==0):
                stack.append(cur)
            if(c[cur]==1):
                flag=False# If Back Edge , Then Not Possible
            cur_adj[s]+=1
        else:
            c[s]=2
            st.append(str(s))
            del stack[-1]

try:
    n,k=map(int,input().split(' '))
    main=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
    depen=[]
    for i in range(n):
        depen.append(list(map(int,input().split(' ')))[1:]);c.append(0)
        cur_adj.append(0)
    c.append(0)
    cur_adj.append(0)
    adjli=[]
    adjli.append(main)#Assuming Main Course at index 0 with dependencies as Main Dependency(main)
    for i in range(len(depen)):
        adjli.append(depen[i])#Appending Other Dependencies
    topo(0)#TopoLogical Sort Order
    st.pop(-1)#popping the assumed Main Couse
    if flag:# IF possible then print
        print(len(st))
        print(' '.join(st))
    else:
        print(-1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e,"error")
```

This code implements what the stack does during recursion. cur_adj is a list where cur_adj[i] holds the index of i's adjacent node to visit next. Once all i's adjacent nodes are visited, i is popped from stack (stack is a normal list which imitates the recursion stack).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was stuck with this error ever since I started Graphs(particularly dfs, due to the recursion). The blog was really helpful and so was your answer. However I would like to know why python hasn't been able to solve this issue? Is it not that big of a deal?

Comment: I think some languages may not give you the freedom of doing some things just because they are potentially harmful. For example, in java you are required to explicitly cast a floating point value to int before assigning it to int variable. But C/C++ gives you the freedom to depend on the implicit casting. The same goes with python vs. C/C++ in recursion stack limit.